# How do I combine two loop in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone please tell me below two loop how do I combine in C#
This is my two loop.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    //assum t1 value 8.00
    t1 += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
}

 foreach (var list in model)
 {
     list.Time = t1.ToString();
     db.Entry(list).State = EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Output

- First record update 8.00
- Second record update 8.15
- Third record update 8.30
- Fourth record update 8.45

Comment: You don't need the first loop. The Second loop just needs to include `t1 += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);` after `list.Time = t1.ToString();`

Comment: If I remove first loop it how can I count i(4 record)

Comment: Why do you need to count `i`? See the answer by Joachim Olsson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "model" contains your four entries:

```
var t1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(8); //Assuming t1 is 8.00 as you said
foreach(var entry in model)
{
    list.Time = t1.ToString();
    t1 += TimeSpam.FromMinutes(15);
    db.Entry(list).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When model contains more than four entries, they will stay separated by 15 minutes (eg. the 5th entry will be 9.00, then 9.15 and so on)

If you wish to ensure the 5th record goes back to 8.00 and 6th to 8.15 and so on, all you need to do is reset the counter after four adds, like so:

```
var t1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(8); //Assuming t1 is 8.00 as you said
var iii = -1;
foreach(var entry in model)
{
    list.Time = t1.ToString() + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(++iii * 15);
    db.Entry(list).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    if(iii == 3)
        iii = -1;
}
```